# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu SDK - errors for fresh install of ubuntu sdk

Tags: sdk, qt5, qt-creator, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-touch

I started to study the development of Ubuntu for the mobile world.
I write here what I did to install the development environment.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks to everyone!

1. Fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop
2. Update and upgrade it
3. In according to communication of Zoltán Balogh of 2016-April and 
   the installation guide of Ubuntu SDK, I followed this instructions sequence:

> - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
> - sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk
> - sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
> - sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk-api-15.04-armhf
> - sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk-ide ubuntu-sdk-dev

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2016-April/039322.html

4. Well! I started to use IDE and I received the update notification of ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf kit. I don't accepted the request update. 
   At this time I have this content for armhf kit:

> ls -l
>   /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/
>
> ```
> drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Components
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:28 Content
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:30 DownloadManager
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Layouts
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:28 MediaScanner.0.1
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 gen 22 20:30 OnlineAccounts
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 PerformanceMetrics
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:30 PushNotifications
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:28 SyncMonitor
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Telephony
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Test
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Unity
> ```

5. I created my first project from this template: QML App with Simple UI(qmake) - (QtQuick2 app with kit using 15.04 click root)

> I have an error on Main.qml for import Ubuntu.Components 1.3
>
> [11:58:52] ii click-reviewers-tools 0.42
>
> Warnings while parsing QML type information of
>   /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components:
>
> Failed to parse
>   "/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes".
>     Error:
>   /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes:1443:39:
>   Meta object revision without matching export.
>     /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes:1452:39:
>   Meta object revision without matching export.
>     /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes:1470:39:
>   Meta object revision without matching export.     Warnings while parsing
>   QML type information of
>   /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/QtMultimedia:
>     Failed to parse
>   "/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/QtMultimedia/plugins.qmltypes".
>     Error:
>   /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/QtMultimedia/plugins.qmltypes:0:0:
>   Expected a single import.

6. Ok, I close ide and reopen it. 
   Well, I accept request update for kits: ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf and ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386

   Now I have this content for amrhf kit

> ```
> ls -l /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/
>
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mag  1 12:16 Content
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mag  1 12:16 DownloadManager
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mag  1 12:16 Layouts
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mag  1 12:16 MediaScanner.0.1
>   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 gen 22 20:30 OnlineAccounts
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mag  1 12:16 PerformanceMetrics
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mag  1 12:16 SyncMonitor
>   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Unity
> ```

The following folders have been deleted after the update request---is it correct?

> ```
> drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Components
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:30 PushNotifications
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Telephony
> drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 gen 22 20:29 Test
> ```

7. Now I have this error on import Ubuntu.Components 1.3:

> ```
> QML module not found
>   import paths /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml
>   For qmake project use QML_IMPORT_PATH variable to add import paths
> ```

8. My qtchooser and qmake version command output:

> ```
> qtchooser -l
>   4
>   5
>   default
>   qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
>   qt4
>   qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
>   qt5
>   --------
>   --------
> qmake -version
>   QMake version 3.0
>   Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> ```